# make the img show when the mouse hover on with jquery

Tags: jquery

the html code :

```
<ul id="top10">
 <li class="test">
    <div class="first">
         <a  href="#"><img src="01.jpg"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="last">
 <a href="#">example one</a>
    </div>
</li>

 <li class="test">
    <div class="first">
         <a  href="#"><img src="01.jpg"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="last">
 <a href="#">example one</a>
    </div>
</li>

 <li class="test">
    <div class="first">
         <a  href="#"><img src="01.jpg"></a>
    </div>
     <div class="last">
```

example one
        
    
     
        
             
        
         
  example one

my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.first img").hide();
    $("ul li:first img").show();
    $("#top li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("img").show();
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work.

i want to get: when open the page. the first image is show, the rest are all hidden. when the mouse hovers on one item title in it. it shows its image. all others are hidden.

**PS: i am sorry.it's ok now. i made a mistake to the ID.but i know my jquery code is bad. is there a better way to get it**

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly? Is the hover function triggered? Does "find" find anything?

Comment: Where is `#top`? Did you mean `#top10`, which is the `id` of the `ul`?

Comment: Where is the element with the ID `#top` that you are referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the correct ID: `top10` instead of `top`. Also, your first two lines can be merged using `:gt(0)`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.first:gt(0) img").hide(); //Every image after the first (index 0) img
    $("#top10 li").hover(function(){ //top 10
        $(this).find("img").show();
    });
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BfHwL/**

Comment: thank U,now i want to make the example one text's font-weight to bold, when the mouse hove on the li. i add this line, $(this).children("div.last a").css("font-weight","bold");but there is no effect. ps: at first i set the font-weight:normal by css

Comment: @enjoylife `.children()` does only select **direct childs** of the current selector. You should at least use `$("div.lasts a", this).css("font-weight", "bold")`. I recommend to use class names instead of direct styles, because it's easier to update class names than style attributes: `.addClass("test")` and `.removeClass("test")` + CSS: `.test{font-weight:bold;}`

Comment: thank u. but when i used $("#top10 li").removeClass("fontweight")
    $("#top10 li").hover(function(){
        $(".firsttop img").hide();
        
        $(this).addClass('fontweight').find("img").show();
                
    });  when i moveout the li. the text also bold. and the first one also bold. i want to get when the mouse hover on the image, the example one text will be bold and the others don't. the default state is using bold to the first example one text.

Comment: @enjoylife Inspect your HTML: You've got `<b></b>` tags, which cause text to be boldfaced. See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfHwL/1/) for the solution. See http://jsfiddle.net/BfHwL/2/ for the **pure CSS** solution.

Comment: many thanks. there are two points with the js ways,1,when you open the page. the first example one text is not bold. when you mouse out all the text, there is no one image showing.i want to show one, when the mouse out.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.first img").hide();
    $("ul li:first img").show();
    $("#top10 li").hover(function(){
        $(".first img").hide();
        $(this).find("img").show();
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vxTRs/

Comment: thank U,now i want to make the example one text's font-weight to bold, when the mouse hove on the li. i add this line, $(this).children("div.last a").css("font-weight","bold");but there is no effect. ps: at first i set the font-weight:normal by css

Comment: @enjoylife you can add in your CSS `.last a:hover {font-weight:bold}`

Comment: thank you, but how to set the  default state which is using bold to the first example one text. when the mouse hover on the image, the example one text will be bold and the others don't.